# Navigation View Can't Change Its Background When It Is Selected/checked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am not able to make the menu item stay with the gray border when selected. The problem is the same as the link below:

[Possible Solution](http://tuchangwei.github.io/2016/07/18/The-solution-that-the-menu-item-of-Navigation-View-can-t-change-its-background-When-it-is-selected-checked/)

Although the colors of the item menu change, the background does not appear. I've read a lot of topics but i don't find a solution for this problem. I am using in my navigationView the following property:

```
app:itemBackground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `StateListDrawable`, the problem was in the property `"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, so I created my own and the problem was solved.